# Sequence notation: $()$, $\{\}$ or $\langle\rangle$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, set-theory

When it comes to sequence concept I see different ways to express it from different sources, for example:

- Wikipedia expresses sequence as $(,)$
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Examples_and_notation
- Some other online sources express sequence as set $\{,\}$
  https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-series.html
- In the book "[Introduction to Algorithm, CLRS](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf)", it is expressed as $\langle,\rangle$

Is it depending on context (CS or Math)? What is the "single source of truth" / standard that I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen all these notations in different analysis textbooks. If you are studying under an instructor then preferably use what the instructor uses or if you are self studying then you are free to use anything and when you write something specifically mention the notations which you are using.

Comment: For me, the two most used notations are $()$ and $\lbrace\rbrace$. As long as you say what notation are you going to use it is ok, I doubt there is a single source of truth in most of math notation. Choose the one you feel confortable with, everyone has a personal favorite notation. Also if you have a teacher or instructor maybe you should use his notation just to make things easier.

Comment: as ( and ) are overloaded I prefer { and }, but this is just my taste

Comment: The problem with {...} is that something similar is used for sets.  So while it is reasonable say that the squares are $\{0,1,4,9,\ldots\}$, it is not so unambiguous to say the Thue–Morse sequence is $\{0,1,1,0,\ldots\}$ as that could be interpreted as being $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Depends. When it comes to giving sequences names, I have seen both $(a_n)$ and $\{a_n\}$ and also the slightly more rigorous $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with its curly brace counterpart as well. When it comes to listing the numbers in a sequence, typically no brackets are used at all, e.g
$$\text{the sequence of primes}=2,3,5,7,11,\dots$$

Comment: There is no reason to think a single notation is best in all settings.

Comment: What do you use for tuples, $(\cdot,\cdot,\cdots)$ or $\langle \cdot,\cdot, \cdots \rangle$? I suggest that you use the same for sequences, which can be seen as countably infinite tuples.